# Selenium webdriver zoom with Ruby for Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, zooming

I am executing automated tests with cucumber and the selenium webdriver connected to Google Chrome and I need to change the zoom at the browser to avoid errors at some automated tests.

The zoom can be changed by pressing the keys *Control + '-'* or *Control + '-'*.

In order to simulate the pressing of theese keys I have added a Hook with this code:

```
Before ('@ChangeBrowserZoom') do
      page = Capybara::page
      page.find("html").send_keys(:control , '+')
      page.find("body").native.send_keys(:control , '+')
end
```

The hook is been called but it is not working.

Comment: At the end, what save my day was to apply this: FocusManager.Page.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style['zoom'] = " + level.to_s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium send_keys method call args one by one in your code. For calling it together use square brackets:

```
Before ('@ChangeBrowserZoom') do
  page = Capybara::page
  page.find("html").send_keys([:control , :add])
end
```

Comment: I have used the brackets as you show but it is still not working.

Comment: Google says that it is not working for Chrome. I also try `page.driver.browser.action.send_keys([:control,:add]).perform` but it is not working for Chrome too. 
If you need just zoom for page you can use script `page.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style['zoom'] = 2")`

Comment: Thank you Artem, your second suggestion page.execute_script("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style['zoom'] = 2") has worked for me.